# Is MySQL always guaranteed to convert DATETIMEs to STRING in this format?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

At the moment if I have a column with type `DATETIME(6)`, say, and extract that value with PHP via ordinary `SELECT datecolumn FROM tablename`, it is apparently always returned as a string matching the following regex

```
/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d+$/
```

Results are zero-padded.

Is this *exact* format guaranteed and documented somewhere? Or is it possible that migrating the code to a server configured differently will yield a string which does not pad leading zeroes or uses slashes instead of hyphens, or some other difference?

Comment: `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` is the canonical string format. I have no idea if the back-end code is y10k compatible, but I think we can safely ignore that for the time being. slashes work, but shouldn't be used, zero-padding doesn't matter.

Comment: I'm not asking about which strings MySQL *accepts* but which ones it *produces*.

Comment: then yes, it will always produce this format. Changing to anything else would be a non-backwards compatible change, and only likely to happen during a major X. version change, not a .y patch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the MySQL declaration about [Date, DateTime and Timestamp DataTypes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html)

You should always expect this format: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

And

> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time
>   parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD
>   HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to
>   '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

Also:

> Invalid DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP values are converted to the
>   “zero” value of the appropriate type ('0000-00-00' or '0000-00-00
>   00:00:00').

Comment: Maybe I'm just being pedantic but that link doesn't seem to guarantee this format in general.

Comment: @spraff, being pedantic makes you more accurate. I added a paragraph from that link. As you see, that is the right format for DATATIME data type. So, you can see it always keep it in that format. Also, you can read more about DATE and TIMESTAMP in the page too

Comment: Thanks. The formatting on that documentation makes my eyes water.

Comment: @spraff, no problem. believe me, I hate MySQL documentation format.